# Getting "User cancelled the requestDevice() chooser." Error with Electron 17.x + Web Bluetooth

Tags: typescript, bluetooth, electron, web-bluetooth

Took a look at the following SO resources:

1. [Web Bluetooth & Chrome Extension: User cancelled the requestDevice() chooser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69874506/web-bluetooth-chrome-extension-user-cancelled-the-requestdevice-chooser)
2. [Electron Web Bluetooth API requestDevice() Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59568260/electron-web-bluetooth-api-requestdevice-error)
3. [Can you manipulate web bluetooth chooser that shows after calling requestDevice()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68057325/can-you-manipulate-web-bluetooth-chooser-that-shows-after-calling-requestdevice)

But their solutions don't seem to be working.

Here's my `main` file:

```
import { app, BrowserWindow } from "electron";

/**
 * Ref: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/quick-start#create-the-main-script-file
 */
async function createWindow(): Promise<BrowserWindow> {
  // Creating a browser window
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
    },
  });

  /**
   * Handle bluetooth connection
   * Ref: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/devices#web-bluetooth-api
   */
  win.webContents.on("select-bluetooth-device", (event, devices, callback) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (devices.length > 0) {
      callback(devices[0].deviceId);
    }
  });

  // Load index.html
  win.maximize();
  await win.loadFile("./dist/renderer/index.html");
  return win;
}

function setUpElectronApp(): void {
  // Browser window
  let win: BrowserWindow | undefined;

  // Enable webBluetooth
  app.commandLine.appendSwitch("enable-experimental-web-platform-features", "true");
  app.commandLine.appendSwitch("enable-web-bluetooth", "true");

  // Create bowser window once the electron app is initialized
  app
    .whenReady()
    .then(() => {
      createWindow()
        .then((response) => {
          win = response;
          console.log(win);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          throw err as Error;
        });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      throw err as Error;
    });

  // Quit the application when it no longer has any open windows
  app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
    if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
      // The action is no-op on macOS due to the OS' behavior (https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/mac-help/mchlp2469/mac)
      // On macOS it is common for applications and their menu bar to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
      app.quit();
      win = undefined;
    }
  });

  // Create a new browser window only when the application has no visible windows being activated
  app.on("activate", () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
      // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
      createWindow()
        .then((response) => {
          win = response;
          console.log(win);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          throw err;
        });
    }
  });
}

setUpElectronApp();
```

Here's some code from the `renderer` file:

```
function onDisconnected(event: Event) {
  const device = event.target as BluetoothDevice;
  console.log(`Device ${device.name} is disconnected.`);
}

export async function deviceConnect(): Promise<DeviceInfo> {

  const device = await navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({
    filters: [
      {
        namePrefix: "Polar Sense",
        manufacturerData: [{ companyIdentifier: 0x006b }], // For 'Polar Electro OY' company.
      },
    ],
    acceptAllDevices: false,
    optionalServices: [0x180d, 0x180f],
  });

  device.addEventListener("gattserverdisconnected", onDisconnected);


  const server = await device.gatt?.connect();

  const heartRateService = await server?.getPrimaryService(0x180d);
  const heartRate = await heartRateService?.getCharacteristic(0x2a37);

  const batteryLevelService = await server?.getPrimaryService(0x180f);
  const batteryLevel = await batteryLevelService?.getCharacteristic(0x2a19);

  return { heartRate, batteryLevel, deviceID: device.name };
}
```

There's a button in my front which triggers the above function when clicked. Constantly, getting the `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: User cancelled the requestDevice() chooser.` error. Tried different versions of Electron as well. Still scratching my head.

Please let me know if accessing Web Bluetooth API in Electron is even possible. Using `"electron": "^17.4.7",` on a macOS Monterey (12.4).

If you can spot anything, please suggest any issues with the approach above.

Comment: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/34443

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to enable Bluetooth access for Electron and VSCode via **System Preferences**.

[image]